# How to do a correct query in mysql with in the string \40

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this string: `alexandre.aba\40gmail.com@gtalk.ofelia.dcc.fc.up.pt` stored as `JabberID` in `USER` table in my database.

The problem is when i execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE JabberID='alexandre.aba\40gmail.com@gtalk.ofelia.dcc.fc.up.pt'
```

It returns:

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

I think it's the \40 that is causing the problem but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Should that be `\0x40` or something?

Comment: When you do `SELECT * FROM `USER`` can you see the backslash in JabberID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about using prepared statements instead since it's safer but to correct the current string look at the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html for a list of special characters. 
I think the `\` should be replaced with `\\`

Comment: it works with the \\... i was expecting a raw method to work with this but i will set this rule on the parser of my queries. thanks :)